# File exists but program throws a FileNotFoundException

Tags: try-catch, filenotfoundexception

```
/*
 *This program checks type casting from String to int/double from a file
 */

import java.io.*;

import java.lang.String;

public class ConvertingStringsToNums {

  public static void main (String[] args){

    File dataFile = new File("/files/scores.dat");
    FileReader in;
    BufferedReader readFile;
    String score;
    double avgScore, totalScores = 0;
    int numScores = 0;
    //------------------------------------------------------------
    try {
      in = new FileReader(dataFile);
      readFile = new BufferedReader(in);

      while((score = readFile.readLine()) != null) {
        numScores += 1;
        System.out.println(score);
        totalScores += Double.parseDouble(score);
      }
      avgScore = totalScores / numScores;

      readFile.close();
      in.close();
    } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
      System.err.println("FileNotFoundException: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.err.println("IOException: " + e.getMessage());
    } //end try/catch

  }
}
```

Comment: If you get a "File doesn't exist" exception trying to open "/files/scores.dat", then it's a safe bet that, for some reason, "/files/scores.dat" doesn't exist :).  SUGGESTIONS: could it be on a different drive (C: vs D:)?  Are you executing the program from a .jar (which would have a different root directory)?  Can you think of any other explanation?

Comment: No, the folder "files" exists in the same file as the .class file and the scores.dat file is inside that folder.

Answer (score 1):

1) If you wish to open a file at an absolute file path on your hard drive:

```
br = new BufferedReader (
  new FileReader(
    new File ("/files/scores.dat")));
```

2) If you wish to open a file at an relative path relative to where you started your app:

```
br = new BufferedReader (
  new FileReader(
    new File ("files/scores.dat")));
```

3) If you wish to open a file at an relative path relative to your class files (particularly relevant for packages and/or for executing from a .jar or a .war):

```
this.getClass().getResourceAsStream ("files/scores.dat");
```

'Hope that helps

Comment: The third one, how exactly would I implement that, and how is that different from the second one in execution?

Comment: Also, I do not quite understand how to implement any of these into the code :$

Answer (score 0):

The reason is can be that you wont be having permission to open the file.
try  `chmod 755 scores.dat` from terminal in order to change the permissions and see if the error still exist.

Comment: I'd think Raziel would instead get Permission Denied, not FileNotFound, if this were the case.

Comment: @jmort253 in my experience, Java throws a FileNotFoundException if the user doesn't have permissions to open the file (at least on Windows).

Comment: "Terminal"...right, I feel dumb but I'm relatively new to Java, knowing only the basics, and unless you are referring to cmd I am confused.

Comment: Terminal for linux is same as cmd prompt for windows. Are you running on windows or linux machine??

Comment: I am running on a Windows 7

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this problem exists in the [javadocs for the File class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html):

> For UNIX platforms, the prefix of an absolute pathname is always "/". Relative pathnames have no prefix. The abstract pathname denoting the root directory has the prefix "/" and an empty name sequence.

In your code, you have the following:

```
File dataFile = new File("/files/scores.dat");
```

According to the documentation, this is an absolute path, which means Java is looking for a folder at the root of the filesystem called "files" and then looking for scores.dat in that folder.

If you instead expect to search for a files directory that is relative to the current directory, you'd need to omit the first `/`:

```
File dataFile = new File("files/scores.dat");
```

The other option is to use an absolute path to your data file, but you may run into problems if you change the location of your project or put the class files in a JAR file.

Try turning up your logging level to DEBUG or ALL so that you can see exactly where the program is trying to look. This will help you adjust your code to target the right folder.

Comment: I tried that though, it still throws the same error: FileNotFoundException: files\scores.dat (The system cannot find the file specified)

Comment: Did you turn up your logging level? Many of these classes have built-in logging that can be turned on by increasing your logging level. It might tell you exactly where the system is trying to look for the file, which means you can either A) move your file to the location it's looking, or B) adjust your file path. Hope this helps!

Comment: So how would I turn up the logging level?

Comment: If you're using a container or framework, you'll likely have a logging.properties or some similar configuration file. Without more information, I can't tell you for sure. However, if you're running java from the command line, you could pass the `-DDEBUG` command line flag to put Java in debug mode, which would show you more information. Hope this helps! :)